# Alert dismiss button not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am changing the alert message dynamically:

```
<div id="alert" hidden="hidden">
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
</div>

$('#alert').addClass("alert alert-danger alert-dismissable")
    .text('Fail to get upload information from YouTube.')
    .show();
```

but the dismiss button is not shown.

Comment: `<div id="alert" hidden="hidden">` why `hidden='hidden'` is there? if you could explain. and also this `-->` : `aria-hidden="true"` in the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the execution of the .text() method you are ending up changing the entire content of the div#alert. However, going by your question, it seems you just want to append the text to the div keeping the button inside the div intact.

That can be achieved with the .append() method instead.

This should work:

```
$('#alert').addClass("alert alert-danger alert-dismissable")
.append('Fail to get upload information from YouTube.')
.show();
```

---

As you've asked to replace an existing text, I would suggest this:
1) Place the previous text inside a span which you can reference later
2) Unhide the div#alert and at the same time change the text of the child span with a new message keeping everything else inside the div in place.

For eg:
If you have your html like this:

```
<div id="alert" hidden="hidden">
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">Hello</button>
 <span id="message">Text before script execution</span>
</div>
```

then the following script will work fine:

```
$('#alert').addClass("alert alert-danger alert-dismissable")
    .show()
    .children('#message').text("Text after script execution");
```

PS: Sometime later if you wish to add html content inside the span, then .html() will work for you, whereas .text() will just treat the contents as text and not render as html code.

Comment: The problem using append will append to the previous text. How can I remove previous text before append?

Comment: I don't see your 'previous text' in the code snippet you have posted. Please post the complete code. Accordingly, we can suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

use .append instead of .text: [Working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/dAs5A/)

```
$('#alert').removeClass('alert alert-info alert-dismissable').addClass("alert alert-danger alert-dismissable").append('Fail to get upload information from YouTube.').show();
```

Comment: if you whant to replace previous message use this code: http://jsfiddle.net/dAs5A/2/

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I can think of is just a minor modification to your code.

```
<div id="alert" hidden="hidden">
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
</div>

$('#alert').addClass("alert alert-danger alert-dismissable")
    .text('Fail to get upload information from YouTube.')
    .append('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>')
    .show();
```

This should do what you want. The button vanishes because it's no longer a part of the `div` tag. Appending it using `append()` will add it after whatever text you want to put in the `div`.